# Onclick apontar para função com $_SERVER

Tags: php, javascript

Devido a uma necessidade obscura do sistema, ao clicar em um botão, preciso saber o IP que acionou o mesmo para direcionar a página correta. Com `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` tenho essa informação. Mas como poderia passar isso para um JS ? Mais ou menos dessa forma:

```
document.getElementById('LIMPAR').onclick = function() {
      if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 'XXX') {
         location.href = '1';
      } ELSE {
         location.href = '2';
      }
}
```

Testando a lógica acima, não tive sucesso. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Talvez no atributo onclick do botão limpar, chamar uma função para fazer esse redirecionamento, passando como parametro o $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] vindo direto do PHP na hora de montar o HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está tentando acessar uma variável do contexto do `PHP`, server, no lado cliente, `javascript`.

Tente algo assim:

```
document.getElementById('LIMPAR').onclick = function() {
  var ip = '<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>';
  if (ip == 'XXX') {
    location.href = '1';
  } ELSE {
    location.href = '2';
  }
}
```

Comment: Exato, dessa forma de certo. Obrigado.